# Implementing New Image Overlay on Existing code (HTML5 and CSS 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get an Image overlay to work with this code?

What I want is a set of icons to overlay, ontop of a image when the cursor moves over it.

http://socialartist.co/index.html

The code in question is HTML 5 and CSS 3, and has quite a lot of mark-up:

```
<ul class="items x_columns">
 <li data-id="id-1" data-cat="#luxury">
  <div class="preview"><a href="#" class="frame">
   <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000008744854-5sr588-large.jpg?d408275" id="imgSmile" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
 <a class="title" href="#">Kirkbridge DNB</a>
 <p>UK | Drum and Bass</p>
</li>
```

When I try to add a new div it just breaks the design (eg messes up the preview class border)

Is there 'an easy way' to just overlay onto an existing image, as above.

I don't really know how to set this up on Fiddle; I am hoping that ppl could just use developer tools (inspect element) on the page URL above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the other overlay picture with the `display: none;` property set and then basically toggle between the two pictures [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/junior87/cVRu7/)

Javascript:

```
jQuery('li[data-id="id-3"] > div').on('hover', 'a', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').toggle();
    jQuery(this).find('div.overlayContent').toggle();
});​
```

Html:

```
<li data-id="id-3" data-cat="#holiday">
    <div class="preview">
        <a href="#" class="frame">
            <img src="http://..." alt="default picture">
            <div class="overlayContent" style="display: none;">...overlay content</div>
            <!--img src="http://..." alt="alternate picture" style="display: none;"-->
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="title" href="#">TEST ME!</a>
    <p>Test this one!</p>
</li>
```

Comment: That is spot on just about - how would I instead of overlaying an image - instead overlay some content (essentially 4 icons/img)?

Comment: Did I understand you right - you want to add 4 images instead of the other img element? Replace the second <img> with a <div> that holds your info. Toggle the <img> and the div then.

Comment: OK I have got this nearly working now, thank's you for help :)

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right:

Add the icon you want to dispay inside the anchor tag:

Quick and dirty example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVSVw/

```
<a href="#" class="frame">
   <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000008744854-5sr588-large.jpg?d408275" id="imgSmile" alt=""/>
   <div class=overlay>ICON</div>
</a>
```

Set it to `display: none` by default and style it with the selector `.frame:hover > .overlay`.

**To your comment**

remove the following line from your style.css:1654:

```
a > .frame:hover, a.frame:hover{
    background: #ffffff;
    /* border: 1px solid #24bfb6;  remove this line */
}
```

Comment: .frame {
 background: #eeeeee;
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
 border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 4px;
 font-size: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

Comment: http://socialartist.co/index.html is the site with existing .frame commented out (hence you can kind of see your code working :)

Comment: Thanks Binarious, that is nearly there but the truth is the other solution does seem to keep the existing styling intact.. (nice grey border etc) http://jsfiddle.net/junior87/cVRu7/